# Report: How to dynamically set the RowSource

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to do something simple, but somehow i fail...sorry didnt find the solution with google

A report or a continous form show 3 fields. The 4th field is a listbox, whose RowSource should depend on one of the other fields.

An example:
A list of user is shown in report, the listbox should now show the permissions of this user in the listbox.

```
SELECT perm_name 
FROM permissions 
WHERE UserID = [UserIDOfThisReportRow])
```

Comment: A report is intended for printing on paper, and it can't have a listbox.  Do you mean a form?

Comment: actually I meant for printing, it does not matter if its a listbox or not, i just need a multi-line subquery for each report row

Comment: If you mean continuous form, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864482/drilldown-using-unbound-comboboxes-with-access-continuous-form/1866708#1866708

Comment: For a report there are a couple of choices. Include the 'permissions' in the recordsource, show your three main fields in a group section and the 'permissions' in the detail section. Or you could include only your main fields' source in the recordsource, show your three main fields in the detail section and use a subreport for the 'permissions'.

Comment: hm seems to be difficult...thanks for your help, I solve this problem another way. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1efDpKjO09KdbNTH3MiJpq_wL0dM_1-CXVPml2NzoN34/edit?usp=sharing