# Access 2010 - combobox - unbound form - displaying data from an existing record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The problem I am having is displaying the correct information in a combobox on an unbound form when a users views/edits data.

The table that populates the combobox:

```
tblLocation   
  idLocation  
  Location
  Location Description
```

In the tblPerson table, there is a FK field called idLocation.  I have a form that allows a user to pick a person from a listbox and displays the information in textboxes and comboboxes.

The combobox is setup with these items:

```
idLocation  <--- column width set to 0
Location
```

The problem I am having is having the data show up correctly in the comobox when I view/edit a new person.

When a person is selected from a ListBox, the information from tblPerson should display in textboxes and comboboxes. The textboxes work just fine.  However, I'm struggling with the comboboxes.  Keep in mind all of the fields

My research finds only two methods on solving this problem:

1. DLOOKUP
2. Manual check and set

If I use the DLOOKUP method:

```
cmbLocation = (DLookup("Location", "tblLocation", "idLocation=" & .Fields("idLocation")))
```

The problem is that msgBox cmbLocation will display the text and not the FK.  If the user tries to edit the data, but makes no changes, it will try to save the text and not the FK.

I found a manual way that does work, but I'm not sure it is the best approach:

```
        For i = 0 To (cmbLocation.ListCount - 1)
            If Val(cmbLocation.Column(0, i)) = Val(.Fields("idLocation").Value) Then
                cmbLocation = cmbLocation.ItemData(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Again, this works - but I have to think that I'm doing something wrong - probably something obvious.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is a continuous form, right? If so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864482/drilldown-using-unbound-comboboxes-with-access-continuous-form/1866708#1866708

Comment: No.  It is a single form.  The listbox is used for selection.  Once a person is selected, the data shows up to the right of it in a couple of textboxes and comboboxes.

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically change which data is displayed in a combobox. in your scenario, i suggest you use the OnClick event of the listbox (once the person is selected). Add the following code:

YourComboBoxName.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation WHERE idLocation=" & FK

If after clicking on a person, the data doesn't change in the combobox, you may need a Me.Refresh

Answer (score 0):

Base the form on a query that left joins in the location column.

Then that field when bound to a text box will will display automatic and without any code. And better is if the actual location value changes, then no update code etc. is required. In fact this is the whole beauty of a relational database!

Comment: Ah, but the form is unbounded.  It's a rather complicated form, using tabs to walk a user through a process.  And the reason for using unbounded is that it provides me greater control for auditing purposes.

Comment: The result of unbound is you writing too much code. A bound form should suffice here. At the end of the day, you’re STILL using a query to grab the one record, and my advice to simply use a query with a left join to bring in the combo description data column STILL stands. This means you don’t need special code. The combo box can and should still be based in a query that brings in the appropriate columns (first column still is PK). Again this will result in you not having to use dlookup() or create a separate or special recordset from the original query that grabs the value for combo display.